# How does one add a conditional inside of a link in jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How does one add a conditional inside of a tag (link/anchor in my case) in jade?

Here's my pseudo code that of course won't work:

```
a(href="/foo", class="if (current_route[1] == 'foo'){active}") Go to Foo
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

`a(href="/foo", class=(current_route[1] === 'foo')? "active" : "") Go to Foo`

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could put it in there as simply as that with the ternary operator. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, is this in the documentation somewhere? If so, a link would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Honestly? I just pulled out a psudocode. I don't know Jade well enough to find you the document. But if a template engine supports in-line code, ternary operator usuage should be the same.

Comment: @k00k this is a little late, but in the jade docs under 'Attributes' it explains that you can just use vanilla JS, it actually uses a ternary operator in the example.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/

Comment: @NuriHodges At the time of this question, the docs were much less verbose. :)