# Jade Templating with if else conditional statement and parameters for navigation

Tags: node.js, pug

```
li()
   a(href="/dashboard")
   span(style = "font-size:16px;" class = "pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard")
   |    Dashboard
li(class = "active")
    a(href="#") 
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload")
    |   Upload
li()
    a(href = "/analyze")
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-stats")
    |   Analyze
li()
    a(href = "/locate")
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-file")
    |   Locate
```

I would like to display the class active for the selected navigation item using a parameter passed from the node.js file. what change do I have to make to the this template file?

Answer (score 0):

```
li(class = parameter ? "active": "")
   a(href="/dashboard")
   span(style = "font-size:16px;" class = "pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard")
   |    Dashboard
li(class = parameter ? "active": "")
    a(href="#") 
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload")
    |   Upload
li(class = parameter ? "active": "")
    a(href = "/analyze")
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-stats")
    |   Analyze
li(class = parameter ? "active": "")
    a(href = "/locate")
    span(style = "font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-file")
    |   Locate
```

try if this works, ternary operator is supported by pug

Comment: Would it not add `active` class to all `li`'s if `parameter` is true? I think he needs to add active class to one of the list elements.

Comment: it will only add `active` if the parameter he sends from backend is a true value.

Comment: I mean if he sends the parameter as true from backend, then all li elements will have `active` class. right? I think each li should match the parameter with a specific value so that only specific li element gets the active class at a time.

Comment: oh sh*t, my apologies, found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713923/node-js-jade-express-how-can-i-create-a-navigation-that-will-set-class-acti