# Why do we need jade or EJS while developing node applications?

Tags: html, node.js, pug, template-engine, ejs

More specifically what I'm trying to say is, why can't we just use pure HTML for that purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of both Jade and EJS for Node.js templating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513168/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-both-jade-and-ejs-for-node-js-templating)

Comment: Of course you can render pure html in your nodejs app, if you don't want to use a template engine.

Answer (score 4):

Jade and EJS are templating engines - they allow you to do things like conditional statements and loops, and give you the ability to break the pages into more modular components (for example, you can have one template with the header in it, and then include that in every other page without having to copy and paste the code). That said, there's nothing stopping you using pure HTML - you just won't get any of those features.